# python - get list of all functions in current module. inspecting current module does not work?

Tags: python

I have following code

```
fset = [ obj for name,obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]) if inspect.isfunction(obj) ]

def func(num):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(fset)
```

prints

```
[]
```

however this

```
def func(num):
    pass

fset = [ obj for name,obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]) if inspect.isfunction(obj) ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(fset)
```

prints

```
[<function func at 0x7f35c29383b0>]
```

so how can fset be list of all functions in current module where fset is defined at the top of all functions ?

EDIT 1: What I am trying to do is

```
def testall(arg):
    return any(f(arg) for f in testfunctions)

def test1(arg):
    #code here
    # may call testall but wont call anyother test*

def test2(arg):
    #code here
    # may call testall but wont call anyother test*
```

More test function may be added in the future. So thats the reason of fset/testfunctions

Comment: why not just have fset as a function that returns a list ._.

Comment: Why do you actually need this? And, especially, why does it need to be defined at the top?

Comment: @abarnert It looks like I can define testfunctions at the bottom. But I thought testall would not be able to use it as it was not defined before it.

Comment: @ato: `test1` has to be defined at the time it's _used_, which is when you _call_ `testall`, not when you define it. If you want to understand the technicalities, I can explain it in an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> EDIT 1: What I am trying to do is

```
def testall(arg):
    return any(f(arg) for f in testfunctions)

def test1(arg):
    #code here
    # may call testall but wont call anyother test*
```

This works just fine:

```
def testall(arg):
    testfunctions = [obj for name,obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]) 
                     if (inspect.isfunction(obj) and 
                         name.startwith('test') and name != 'testall')]
    return any(f(arg) for f in testfunctions)

def test1(arg):
    #code here
    # may call testall but wont call anyother test*
```

In this case, `testfunctions` isn't evaluated until `testall` is called, so there's no problem here—by that time, all top-level module code (including the `test1` definition) will have been evaluated, so `testfunctions` will get all of the top-level functions. (I'm assuming here that `testall` or `test1` is being called from an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block at the bottom of the module, or another script is doing `import tests; tests.test1(10)`, or something similar.)

In fact, even if you explicitly named `test1` and `test2`, there would be no problem:

```
def testall(arg):
    testfunctions = ('test1',)
    return any(f(arg) for f in testfunctions)

def test1(arg):
    #code here
    # may call testall but wont call anyother test*
```

Again, `test1` is already defined by the time you call `testall`, so everything is fine.

---

If you want to understand why this works, you have to understand the stages here.

When you import a module, or run a top-level script, the first stage is compilation (unless there's already a cached .pyc file). The compiler doesn't need to know what value a name has, just whether it's local or global (or a closure cell), and it can already tell that `sys` and `inspect` and `test1` are globals (because you don't assign to them in `testall` or in an enclosing scope).

Next, the interpreter executes the compiled bytecode for the top-level module, in order. This includes executing the function definitions. So, `testall` becomes a function, then `test1` becomes a function, then `test2` becomes a function. (A function is really just the appropriate compiled code, with some extra stuff attached, like the global namespace it was defined in.)

Later, when you call the `testall` function, the interpreter executes the function. This is when the list comprehension (in the first version) or the global name lookup (in the second) happens. Since the function definitions for `test1` and `test2` have already been evaluated and bound to global names in the module, everything works.

What if you instead later call `test1`, which calls `testall`? No problem. The interpreter executes `test1`, which has a call to `testall`, which is obviously already defined, so the interpreter calls that, and the rest is the same as in the previous paragraph.

So, what if you put a call to `testall` or `test1` in between the `test1` and `test2` definitions? In that case, `test2` wouldn't have been defined yet, so it would not appear in the list (first version), or would raise a `NameError` (second version). But as long as you don't do that, there's no problem. And there's no good reason to do so.

---

If you're worried about the horrible performance cost of computing `testfunctions` every time you call `testall`… Well, first, that's a silly worry; how many times are you going to call it? Are your functions really so fast that the time to call and filter `getmembers` even shows up on the radar? But if it really is a worry, just cache the value in your favorite of the usual ways—mutable default, privat global, function attribute, …:

```
def testall(arg, _functions_cache=[]):
    if not _functions_cache:
        _functions_cache.extend([…])
```

Answer (score 11):

It can't be. Function definitions are *executed* in Python. The functions don't exist until their definition is executed. Your `fset` variable can't be defined until after the functions are defined.

Comment: How about getting it from another module which sets fset by importing and inspecting the current module ?

Comment: Depending on what the OP is actually trying to do, it might be sufficient to just define an `fset` _function_ at the top, then call that whenever he needs the value. Then, as long as he doesn't call the function before all of the other functions are defined, everything will be fine. (Except he might want to add `and name != 'fset'` to the end of his comprehension. It's already over 100 characters long, so what's another 15 past the edge of the screen?)

Comment: @ato: If the other module imports the current module, (a) it will execute the code in the current module, which means a circular import, and (b) the value still won't be available until the entire current module is executed.

Comment: @kindall: By the way, great explanation. I probably would have gone on for half a page about the compiler and other irrelevant stuff to say what you covered in two lines. :)

Comment: @kindall: As you'll notice, to answer the OP's edit, I ended up going on for half a page about the compiler. :) Maybe you can answer the followup more clearly and concisely.

Comment: Alternatively, open `__FILE__` and parse all `def \S+:` lines yourself.

Answer (score 7):

To exclude any imported functions this works:

```
import sys
import inspect 
[obj for name,obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]) 
                     if (inspect.isfunction(obj) and 
                         name.startswith('test') and
                         obj.__module__ == __name__)]
```